# "npm run dev" failed in window 10

Tags: npm, laravel-5.4

I recently create a laravel project 5.4 version. I try to compile webpack.mix.js by run "npm run dev". But it show the current error.[image]

1. I using window 10
2. I have changed the path to C:\Program Files\nodejs
3. Change .bin folder name to bin
4. Npm and nodejs are installed.
5. Path is set like this -> C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm

is this the problem of window or i set something wrong here? Really smashing my head finding the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just update node.js and npm. From your screen shot:

> Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

Comment: This is listed at every node error, in my experience most of the times it doesn't solve anything.